# System Images are not showing up in my Android Virtual Device list

Tags: android, xamarin

[image]

Above you can see I have almost every 7.1 system image installed, yet my only options for CPU in my AVD are for TV or the wearable... what am I doing wrong? I just want to emulate a regular old Android phone :(

Answer (score 2):

You are using SDK Tools v25 which do not support the new `avdmanager` images. You will need to use SDK Tools v26 and the [Xamarin Android Device Manager](https://blog.xamarin.com/first-look-xamarin-android-device-manager-preview/).

Comment: Interesting, how do I upgrade my SDK? Seems like I was not given an option for version when Installed Xamarin two days ago.

Comment: Actually, I think you may be wrong. I have SDK Platform 27 installed (see above image).

Comment: SDK Platform != SDK Tools, check the tools tab.